# How can I set in Python the connectivity for the SimpleITK `ConnectedThreshold` filter?

Tags: python, image-processing, itk, simpleitk

How can I set in Python the pixel connectivity for the SimpleITK `ConnectedThreshold` filter applied to a single channel 2D image?

```
import SimpleITK as sitk

# define a simple image from an array
img = sitk.GetImageFromArray([[128,128,0],[128,128,128],[0,128,0]])

# get the Region Growing segmentation
out = sitk.ConnectedThreshold(img,seedList=[(1,1)],lower=127,upper=129,replaceValue=42)

# print the result as a vector:
a = sitk.GetArrayViewFromImage(out)
print(a)
```

I get this output (it seems to me 8-connected regions is considered):

```
[[42 42  0]
 [42 42 42]
 [ 0 42  0]]
```

How can I get this output (obtained when using the 4-connected regions)?

```
[[ 0 42  0]
 [42 42 42]
 [ 0 42  0]]
```

Comment: Probably my setting `Connectivity` parameter: https://simpleitk.org/doxygen/latest/html/classitk_1_1simple_1_1ConnectedThresholdImageFilter.html#a000d702b3571099f46577102f8005611

Comment: @Dženan, ok but how can I write it in Python?

Comment: Maybe `...replaceValue=42,Connectivity=FaceConnectivity` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

This comment [How can I set in Python the connectivity for the SimpleITK `ConnectedThreshold` filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66655867/how-can-i-set-in-python-the-connectivity-for-the-simpleitk-connectedthreshold?noredirect=1#comment117841921_66655867) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/276168/d%c5%beenan suggests a trial and error approach.

First of all the original question has an error: `[[128,128,0],[128,128,128],[0,128,0]]` must give the same result with 4-connectivity and 8-connectivity because:

1. for 4-connectivity: `(0,0)` is 4-connected with `(0,1)` that is 4-connected with the seed at `(1,1)`.
2. for 8-connectivity: `(0,0)` is 8-connected with `(1,1)`.

So, following the above mentioned comment I did some experiments and I found that: the keyword argument name is `connectivity` and the value `0` means 4-connectivity; the value `1` means 8-connectivity and it seems to me that any other value `>1` gives an image where every pixel has a zero value.

This is the code:

```
import SimpleITK as sitk
import numpy as np

# define a simple image from an array
v = np.array([[128,0,0],[0,128,0],[0,0,0]])
print('input:\n',v)
img = sitk.GetImageFromArray(v)

# get the Region Growing segmentation
out = sitk.ConnectedThreshold(img,seedList=[(1,1)],lower=127,upper=129,replaceValue=42,connectivity=0)

# print the result as a vector:
a = sitk.GetArrayViewFromImage(out)
print('output, connectivity=0\n',a)

# get the Region Growing segmentation
out = sitk.ConnectedThreshold(img,seedList=[(1,1)],lower=127,upper=129,replaceValue=42,connectivity=1)

# print the result as a vector:
a = sitk.GetArrayViewFromImage(out)
print('output, connectivity=1\n',a)

# get the Region Growing segmentation
out = sitk.ConnectedThreshold(img,seedList=[(1,1)],lower=127,upper=129,replaceValue=42,connectivity=2)

# print the result as a vector:
a = sitk.GetArrayViewFromImage(out)
print('output, connectivity=2\n',a)
```

This is the output:

```
input:
 [[128   0   0]
 [  0 128   0]
 [  0   0   0]]
output, connectivity=0
 [[ 0  0  0]
 [ 0 42  0]
 [ 0  0  0]]
output, connectivity=1
 [[42  0  0]
 [ 0 42  0]
 [ 0  0  0]]
output, connectivity=2
 [[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]
```

Anyway I can't find a documentation for the above... so my conclusion is that SimpleITK is not so simple :-)

Comment: Well, it's simple relative to the original ITK.

Comment: @DaveChen :-) I read you are a developer for SimpleITK: is there anywhere doc specially targeted to Python? Otherwise maybe it's best for me to use ITK straight with Python, isn't it? Thank you.

Comment: Well, in this case, like many other ITK filters, SimpleITK's documentation is pulled directly from ITK's docs.  From a documentation standpoint they're not much different. I'm not a fan of ITK's templatization and how it's exposed in python, but if it suits your needs better, go for it.